# How can I see log messages in external tool like DebugView during a debug session?

Tags: debugging, serilog

I am using Serilog to log messages to Debug View. It works great while application is not during debug session. While in debug session all the messages goes to output window and Debug View is not getting any.
Tried .WriteTo.Debug / .WriteTo.Trace / .WriteTo.Console, all are working when not debugging and fail during debug.

Any ideas how to enable messages getting out into an external tool while debugging?

Comment: What is the project type?

Comment: The project is console csproj

Comment: Next question, what is `Debug View` as it's not clear what you are referring too.

Comment: DebugView is the SysInternals debug tool

Comment: The sink `Serilog.Sinks.Debug` does not work with SysInternals DebugView, only inside of Visual Studio.

Comment: It works when not running in debug mode. My question is how to make logs to DebugView during debug session

Answer (score 0):

Exists an addon for visual studio that forwards the output window to the DebugView++

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JanWilmans.OutputForwarder2022